# Display requested JSON feed as URL

Tags: javascript, anchor, window.location

I have a form that makes a request for a JSON feed, and displays the results. I need to be able to provide a link to the raw feed to the user as well. I have the following code that pulls the selections from inputs and generates a URL for the request:

```
document.getElementById('region').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

      window.location.href = '/editorialPortal' + '?' + this.id + '=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

});
```

I need to be able to put `window.location.href = '/editorialPortal' + '?' + this.id + '=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;` into an anchor link, but having trouble getting that setup.

I have this `<a href="<' + "script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = '/editorialPortal' + '?' + this.id + '=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"'</script>">JSON</a>` , but its not working correctly due to quotation mark placement.

You'll see in the console.log event that the URL is generated by the form in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/a75gqag7) I need to be able to set that generated URL as the JSON feed it returns

Comment: give some feedback if you dont like the post when downvoting

Comment: @BobSinclar, how is that statement relevant to my question?

Comment: it was a comment to the downvoter sorry maybe i should delete it

Comment: What down vote? This question is at "0"?

Comment: i upvoted to bring it back to 0. Also a jsfiddle might make it easier to see the issue your having.

Comment: Ok. Any pointers on how to get this to work?

Comment: when you say i have this thats whats rendered to the dom in your html ? its slightly hard to follow without a js fiddle .

Comment: "'</script>">JSON</a> i dont see where that is coming from

Comment: You'll see in the console.log event that the URL is generated by the form in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/a75gqag7/

I need to be able to set that generated URL as the JSON feed it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the `<a>` you want to update already exists, already has the text of 'JSON', and has an id of `link` (if not, [badrequest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28240047/879121) shows you how to add a new `<a>` to the page). So we just need to update it's `href` attribute with the selected values.

```
var regionBox = document.getElementById('region'),
    region = regionBox.options[regionBox.selectedIndex].value,
    durationBox = document.getElementById('duration'),
    duration = durationBox.options[durationBox.selectedIndex].value,
    link = document.getElementById('link'),
    newHref = '/editoralPortal/?region=' + region + '&duration=' + duration;

link.href = newHref;
```

Comment: I need to be able to pull the generated URL that will have the region and duration in it, into an anchor link. So I should get `<a href="/editoralPortal/?region=US&duration=20">JSON</a>` for example.

Comment: If you look in the console of the fiddle I provided, you'll see the URL that needs to be generated and rendered based on what the user selects and submits: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/a75gqag7/2/

Comment: @Matt that fiddle makes more sense. I would update your question to include it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is getting very close, but its oddly not pulling the values from the drop downs, as you can see from this updated fiddle when hovering over the "JSON feed" link. http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/a75gqag7/3/

Comment: Got it figured out. I had the necessary variables in another area of the code, and just had to fix the URL to adapt to those.

Comment: @Matt well I guess you don't need it then but I updated your jsfiddle to work: http://jsfiddle.net/a75gqag7/4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the anchor tag dynamically on the DOM

```
// create anchor and set attributes

var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.setAttribute('href', 'your generated link goes here');
anchor.innerHTML = 'Whatever you want to show up on page';

// nest anchor tag somewhere on page

var blabla = document.getElementById('blabla);
blabla.appendChild(anchor);
```

Hope this helps!